# detect when ajax upload is unexpectedly terminated

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have this ajax uploading code which sends data back stating whether or not the upload was successful. However it only knows if the files had no errors and were moved to there target path once the file has already uploaded, if the upload is terminated before it is complete, no data will be returned. Is there a way I can listen to detect the moment the upload is unexpectedly terminated and alert the page?

```
$('#send').click(function() {

 var fileInput = $('#file')[0];
     var data = new FormData();

  for(var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; ++i){     
      data.append('file[]',fileInput.files[i]);
   }
     $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    method:'POST',
    url:'upload.php',
    headers:{'Cache-Control':'no-cache'},
    data:data,
    contentType:false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(response){
        var return_data = response;

        if(return_data !== 'success') {
        $('#status').html('uploaded'); 
        }
        else if(return_data == 'success') {
           $('#status').html('upload failed'); 
        }         
      }
   });
});
```

and in upload.php:

```
if($_FILES['file']['error'][$key] == 0
   && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key],"video/test/$name")){
        echo "success";
 }else{
        echo "failed";
```

Comment: why are you using javascript ?? can't you do it with jquery ?

Comment: This example might help you out: http://js1.hotblocks.nl/tests/ajax/file-drag-drop.html

Comment: thanks for the link I'll check it out

Comment: jQuery offers an great and easy abstraction for ajax requests, including callbacks in case of errors. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: well if you want to find out the progress then javascript can be used, but the task you are asking, jquery is well suited for that. Regards

Comment: OK, I have made it into jquery. I think that should work(not tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#send').click(function() {
   var fileInput = $('#file')[0];
   var data = new FormData();

   for(var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; ++i){     
       data.append('file[]',fileInput.files[i]);
   }

   $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        method:'POST',
        url:'upload.php',
        headers:{'Cache-Control':'no-cache'},
        data:data,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,

        beforeSend: function(response){
            // before send do some func if u want
        },

        success: function(response){
            var return_data = response;

            if(return_data !== 'success') {
               $('#status').html('uploaded'); 
            } else if(return_data == 'success') {
               $('#status').html('upload failed'); 
            }         
        },

        complete: function(response){
            // do some func after complete if u want
        },

        error: function(response){
            // here is what u want
            alert ("Error: " + response.statusText);
        },

    });
    // end ajax call
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an `error` method to your `$.ajax` options object.

Answer (score 1):

One of the parameters for $.ajax is error. you can specify a function to run if the page doesn't return status 200.

From the jquery docs (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

"error
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event."